# Django rest framework: De serializing a string to an integer and vice versa

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

We are using Django Rest framework to serialise and deserialise json response from a third party API. I need to translate the string field values to a numeric value in our system.

The JSON response is given below

```
{
   "result": "win" # Other values include "loss"/"inconclusive"/"pending"
}
```

Django Model

```
class Experiment(Model):
   RESULTS = (
       (1, 'win'),
       (2, 'loss'),
       (3, 'inconclusive'),
   )
   inferred_result = models.IntegerField(choices=RESULTS, null=True, blank=True)
```

Django Serializer Class

```
class ResultsSeializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Need to convert "result" from "string" to "int" and vice versa.

    class Meta:
        model = models.Experiment
```

I want to convert the `inferred_result` integer value to `string` equivalent and vice versa. I could use this approach: [Django rest framework. Deserialize json fields to different fields on the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713058/django-rest-framework-deserialize-json-fields-to-different-fields-on-the-model) if this is a good idea to convert integers to string. How do I convert string to int? I am new to django rest api and django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display string instead of int you can use [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) model's attribute. To convert string to int during creation process you can override [`create()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving) method like this:

```
class ResultsSeializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    inferred_result = serializers.CharField(source='get_inferred_result_display')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Experiment
        fields = ('inferred_result',) 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        dispplayed = validated_data.pop('get_inferred_result_display')
        back_dict = {k:v for v, k in models.Experiment.RESULTS}
        res = back_dict[dispplayed]
        validated_data.update({'inferred_result': res})
        return super(ResultsSeializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Same way you need to override `update()` if you need.

Comment: how do I translate "result" in json response to "inferred_result" field. I don't understand what you mean by "get_result_display".

Comment: @Kartik did you read docs by link [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)?

Comment: @BearBrown I did but "source" is used to populate the field, and is not used to read from it.  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source. "get_Foo_display" is used to provide the a user friendly value from the model, but it does not tell if it is serializable.  The db column also accepts null. How do I translate null to a user friendly string. I don't want to show "None" as an output.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner What do you mean "get_new_int_display"? I am assuming that you mean "inferred_result" when you enter "new_int"? Does "get_result_display" map to the method in django models?

Comment: @Kartik oh it should be `get_inferred_result_display` actually. I thought your field named `result`. Yes get_inferred_result_display is model's method which translate int to human readble string for choices field named inferred_result

Comment: @BearBrown One last question, how do I translate the value of django model field to its string equivalent. I am assuming I need to override to_representation?

Comment: @Kartik but `get_inferred_result_display` does exacly same. It's translate DB value to string. My first version of ansver included `to_representation` but it's not necessary you can specify `source='get_inferred_result_display'` in the field declaration.